# Send mp3 file over socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, audio, tcp, mp3

I'm facing a problem trying to send an mp3 file through a socket

This is the code I use to read the mp3 file

```
FILE *file;
char *audio;
unsigned long fileLen;

file = fopen("AAAA.mp3", "rb");
if (!file)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file");
    return;
}

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileLen = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

audio = (char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
if (!audio)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
    fclose(file);
    return;
}

fread(audio, fileLen, 1, file);
fclose(file);
```

And then I have this function to send the content

```
int send_message(int sockfd, uint16_t code, char *message)
{
    int bytes_sent;
    uint16_t l_msg;
    uint16_t l_msg_net;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE+CODE_LEN+MSG_LEN];

    l_msg = strlen(message) + 1;
    l_msg_net = htons(l_msg);

    code = htons(code);

    // Save message code
    memcpy(buffer, &code, CODE_LEN);
    // Save message length
    memcpy(buffer + CODE_LEN, &l_msg_net, MSG_LEN);
    // Save message
    memcpy(buffer + CODE_LEN + MSG_LEN, message, l_msg);

    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, buffer, (l_msg + CODE_LEN + MSG_LEN), 0);

    return(bytes_sent);
}
```

If I save the buffer (**audio** var from the first piece of code) to a file before send it, it works great, but when I try to save it on the server side, it gets corrupted. Also, the content of the buffer is this ??$?

I don't know why, I think it's because is a binary file.

Any thoughts? Maybe I'm sending the data on a wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it has strlen() in it, so it can't be good.  99% of all network/socket code with strlen() calls is borken.

Comment: @MartinJames It's 100% assuming binary streams.

Comment: I tried with sizeof(message) but is the same thing...

Comment: You really should read some docs. Really. `sizeof` pointer is the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **binary** file, meaning bytes containing `'\0'` are legitimate data.

This line:

```
fileLen = ftell(file);
```

tells you how many bytes to send.

Also, `send()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.  Per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send):

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

Even better, send the file directly by using `sendfile()`:

```
struct stat sb;
int fd = open( "AAAA.mp3", O_RDONLY );
fstat( fd, &sb );
// first send the file size - NB this is not correct as it
// assumes sizeof( sb.st_size ) is the same on the other 
// end *and* has the same endianness
write( sockfd, &sb.st_size, sizeof( sb.st_size ) );
ssize_t bytesSent = sendfile( sockfd, fd, NULL, sb.st_size );
```

Comment: So, there's no other way to send the file rather than using sendfile? The thing is that I don't understand why the data is corrupted on the other side. It seems I cannot send the buffer as a "string"

Comment: @Ernes - You can't send it as a string because it's **not** a string.  And there are lots of ways to send a file out though a socket if you want to write the code.  They all pretty much include writing multiple lines of code to copy the data into user space and then write it out to the socket.  `sendfile()` sends the data using one line of code, and does it directly without having to copy the data into user space when it's read and then back out when it's written to the socket.